# updateAttributes on quantity & stock availability

Tags: attributes, product-attribute

I have created a custom attribute which allows me to disable products that have past a specified date. First I fetch the collection (getCollection), filter by those with an end date and with status 'enabled' and then save it in $toBeZeroedCollection. Then:

```
$toBeZeroedIds = $toBeZeroedCollection->getAllIds();
    unset($toBeZeroedCollection);
    if ($toBeZeroedIds) {
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
                     $toBeZeroedIds,
                     array('status' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED),
                     Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID
            );
```

The above code disables the product. But I want to also set the quantity to zero and stock availability to 'Out of Stock'. Do you know how I can achieve this?

I tried variations of the following but have had no success, even the disabled action no longer works with these variations.

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
->updateAttributes(
                     $toBeZeroedIds,
                     array('status' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED, 
                    'is_in_stock' => Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Status::STATUS_OUT_OF_STOCK, 
                    'qty' => 0),
                     Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID
            );
```

**Update**

I got this working using product ids, with code similar to Parassood's below.

```
foreach($toBeZeroedIds as $productId){

        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
        $stockItem->setData('qty', 0);
        $stockItem->save();


    }
```

I also had to lengthen my cron settings as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/21202940/3779933

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop through the $zeroCollection and do something like:

```
foreach($zeroCollection as $product){

  $stockItem = $product->getStockItem();
  $stockItem->setIsInStock(false)
            ->setQty(0)
            ->save();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I use this, it doesn't affect the stock or quantity of the products. Also the disable function in my code stops working too. Do you know what else I could try? For example is there a way to set stock status and quantity using the product id?

Comment: As commented in my edit, your code wasn't the fix I needed, but it helped me find the solution. Thanks